# How can I record an audio stream in a m3u to mp3, with python-vlc?

Tags: python, vlc, libvlc

I'm trying to record an audio stream in an m3u to mp3, using python-vlc.

The stream: http://82.135.234.195:8000/opus3.mp3.m3u

I would expect the following to work.

```
import vlc
import time

instance = vlc.Instance("--sout=#transcode{vcodec=none,acodec=mp3,ab=128,channels=2,samplerate=44100}:file{dst=test.mp3,no-overwrite}")
player = instance.media_list_player_new()
media = instance.media_list_new([http://82.135.234.195:8000/opus3.mp3.m3u])
player.set_media_list(media)
player.play()

time.sleep(30)

player.stop()
player.release()
instance.release()
```

What am I missing?